# Change Background of activity dynamically through code

Tags: java, android

I have a requirement of changing the background of the current activity after some USER ACTIOn

Following id the Code i have written

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),readBitmap(Uri.fromFile(new File(getFilesDir(), imageName))));
this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).setBackground(d);
this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).refreshDrawableState();
public Bitmap readBitmap(Uri selectedImage) {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 1; // reduce quality
    ParcelFileDescriptor pFileDescriptor = null;
    try {
        //fileDescriptor = this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(selectedImage, "r");
        pFileDescriptor = this.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(selectedImage, "r");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(pFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), null, options);
            pFileDescriptor.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return bm;
}
```

Here is the content.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_img_body"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

Also if i remove the backgroung set in the XML it works just fine!!
am confused

MOdified XML (Working)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

Can anyone Please suggest.

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 1):

try `this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).setBackgroundDrawable(d);`

Comment: tried..Not worked..
BTW have edited the POST to add some info

Comment: Edited!..:-)..Please let me know if you need any other info

Comment: try using id in relative layout and change background of it using relativeLayout id.

Comment: i cant do that!.. bcoz i have written this code in a parent class(BASEACTIVITY)..Which is extended by all my activities...So the id keeps changing

Comment: method `setBackgroundDrawable()` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

First give id to your layout

second findviewbyid that layout

third layout.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ready));

problem solve !!!

Comment: i cant do that!..
bcoz i have written this code in a parent class(BASEACTIVITY)..Which is extended by all my activities...So the id keeps changing